# SQL - Compare row changes with most recent and previous entry

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to find the most elegant way of comparing multiple entries in a single table. We have a table that holds Audit data, but it just says what the current value is. I want to look back at the entry for this same object to see if it is different. Here is an example table schema:

```
ObjectID         Value            Timestamp
a                 granted          08/24/2016 17:56:59
b                 unset            08/24/2016 12:17:59
b                 unset            08/24/2016 11:17:45
a                 unset            08/23/2016 07:56:59
a                 deny             08/23/2016 20:12:59
b                 deny             08/22/2016 05:45:59
```

I'm trying to find when the most recent a,b is different from the previous a,b. In the example above I would find the first a changed from unset-> granted, and the last b went from deny->unset.

I'm thinking I'll have to do a sub-query and select the row before the latest and compare the value. Thought there might be a better way.

Comment: You should add what you think the query would be and most important the expected results.

Comment: Where is your code! What have you tried so far?

Comment: To get you started, I have found that you can do many problems like this elegantly using a CTE with row_number and self-joining.

Comment: You should also add what version of SQL Server you're using. More recent versions have functions that can make this easier, so compatibility with versions is important, and the best answer can differ based on the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this can help

```
Declare @Table table (ObjectID varchar(25), Value varchar(25), Timestamp Datetime)
Insert into @Table values 
('a','granted','08/24/2016 17:56:59'),
('b','unset','08/24/2016 12:17:59'),
('b','unset','08/24/2016 11:17:45'),
('a','unset','08/23/2016 07:56:59'),
('a','deny','08/23/2016 20:12:59'),
('b','deny','08/22/2016 05:45:59')
```

---

```
Declare @XML xml
Set @XML = (Select * from @Table for XML RAW)

;with cteBase as (
    Select ObjectID     = r.value('@ObjectID','varchar(25)') 
          ,Timestamp    = r.value('@Timestamp','datetime')
          ,Item         = Attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)')
          ,Value        = Attr.value('.','varchar(max)')
    From @XML.nodes('/row') AS A(r)
    Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*[local-name(.)!="ObjectID"]') AS B(Attr)
)
,cteExt as (Select *,LastValue =Lag(Value) over (Partition By ObjectID,Item Order by Timestamp) From cteBase)
Select ObjectID
      ,Item
      ,Before=LastValue
      ,After =Value
      ,Timestamp
 From  cteExt 
 Where Value<>LastValue and LastValue is not null
   and Item not in ('Timestamp')
 Order By ObjectID,Timestamp
```

Returns

```
ObjectID    Item    Before  After   Timestamp
a           Value   unset   deny    2016-08-23 20:12:59.000
a           Value   deny    granted 2016-08-24 17:56:59.000
b           Value   deny    unset   2016-08-24 11:17:45.000
```